# will Python script work in spark using pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, bigdata

I developed a python script for a machine learning use case, and now I want to execute that script in the pyspark shell of spark. 
Will I be able to do it straight away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Spark's in-memory distributed processing power, you would need to use the pyspark API to define the Spark Context and create RDDs (Resilient Distributed Dataset). Standard python code can run inside pyspark shell but it would be the same as running the code on a single node. Spark does have their own machine learning libraries but in general the features are not as rich as what is available in python. Hope this helps.

Comment: can i install all the python modules(like pandas, sklearn... etc.) in pyspark? if yes then how to do that?

Comment: Installation of Python modules are independent from PySpark.

Assuming if you are working under Unix environment. Check if you have "pip" utility installed.

For example:
which pip

Will give you the location of pip command in your file system.

If "pip" is available you can try:

pip install pandas

Depends on the setup of your site packages. You may have to manually download all the packages and make them available in your python repository in order for pip to install them.

For further reading, this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/